# MaxTemperature example for MapReduce on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run MaxTemperature example from MapReduce. But I couldnot find the MaxTemperature.jar in Hadoop MapReduce Examples. Can someone help me out finding the jar file or what is the possibility of executing this program and see the output?

Comment: Pssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064300/mapreduce-java-program-to-calaculate-max-temperature-not-starting-to-run-it-is-r Here you have all the code with which you can create jar. You dont get this jar within hadoop installables.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;






public class Temp {

  public static class Map extends  Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
   // private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable();
  //  private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException  InterruptedException
{
      String line = value.toString();
      String year=line.substring(0,4);
      //StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
     // while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      // word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
       // output.collect(word, one);
      int Temp=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(6,8));
      context.write(new Text(year),new IntWritable(Temp));
      }
    }
  }
/*
  public static class Reduce extends  Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
     // int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int sum=0;
      while (values.hasNext()) {
          sum += values.next().get();
      }
      output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
  }*/
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
{
@Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {

        int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
           for (IntWritable value : values) {
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
     }
             context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
      }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Temp.class);
    conf.setJobName("Temp");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
  }
}
```

make jar file of this program and execute command

```
hadoop jar Temp.jar Temp /hdfs_inputFile /hdfs_inputFile
```

Comment: Sorry, I have the source code but I wanted to know what is the classpath that I can set to compile this program in order to make jar